# HTML/Python Page Cataloging System

Tags: python, html

I've been taking a Coursera course from Duke University on Chemistry. I happen to take a lot of notes when watching the video lectures, and, well, ... there's a lot. I must have around 30 pages already, in no particular order, in my binder, and some form of sorting would be cool. I've come up with some Python 3.3 code, but it's incomplete. My goal: Be able to `search()` the database with a keyword, and be returned a list of the pages containing that word.

Anyway, here's my checklist:

- √ Debug/Finish `search()` function
- Add `lookup()` function
- (Eventually) integrate full code into HTML...?

The `lookup()` function is my priority right now;
In its finished state, it'll return what binder & section a given page is in.

Any help or comments would be really helpful.
   
Thanks!

**EDIT:** [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s95j1b2d3vimzya/Page%20Catalouge%20%28FULL%29.py?dl=0) is the syncing Dropbox file.

Answer (score 0):

Try a framework called [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It uses Python to render HTML, combined with data retrieved from a SQL database.

You can combine a Django project with the code you are creating right now.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably use this when I finish the code.